# Ionic 2 Visual Studio template - Live reload does not work

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

I downloaded and installed latest version of the Visual Studio Ionic 2 templates for Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

To my frustration, I've found that the live reload feature of the Cordova does not work at all. When I modify HTML, the only way for Cordova Simulate to reflect these changes is stop debugging and redeploy the project, which takes a considerable amount of time and makes the development workflow a real pain.

Another issue occurs whenever there is more than one Ionic project in progress. I found that because Ionic is using the same port for deployment then when one of the projects is launched, the launched app will get confused as to which app I'm requesting, and will often show the other app instead of the one I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: No unfortunately I've just had to make do without it!

Comment: @SteveKennedy see both answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually configure the "watch" task to be started when the project is opened. Add the following field:

```
"ProjectOpened": [ "watch" ]
```

to the "-vs-binding" object in your package.json.

I believe, it was supposed to be there by default (upon project creation), but it isn't. Also, you could try to configure it via Task Runner Explorer, but it didn't work either (at least, for me).

Also don't forget to re-open your solution after that change.

Comment: hmm it seems this comes close to a final solution - I can see the watch binding now appear in the Task Runner Explorer, however when I make changes to HTML for example, when the reload occurs, the browser just goes completely blank with no error messages thrown. Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to complete a solution - seems there were two issues here. Visual Studio's support for Ionic is pants.

Comment: Well, when the browser goes completely blank, this usually means some exception at the app startup. And that's a different issue. 
Try to look into JavaScript console for some error messages, that would help to investigate further.
Try different browser.

Answer (score 3):

Please see @scale_tones's answer for part of the answer.

I looked into this further and found that there was an extra step that needed to be made here to resolve the issue. It turns out that a fix was implemented for this issue, but it doesn't appear to have been released anywhere as far as I can see.

However, it is possible to apply the fix manually. To do that, follow these steps:

1) Copy the contents of the **watcher.js** file from Github [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-simulate/blob/1e30eee1213dc4e11ccb90a9f87448e9295443ac/src/server/live-reload/watcher.js)

2) Use your file explorer to search for the watcher.js file on your machine. On my machine, the file was located at the following location:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\a43fc8f0\taco-toolset-6.3.1\node_modules\cordova-simulate\src\server\live-reload

Replace the watcher.js file with the one from Github. This fixed the issue for me, and live reload now works for me.

Comment: Finally a working solution for Visual Studio 2017 Ionic 2 Live Preview / Automatic Refresh!

Comment: Oh my god. A big thanks! Was looking for this for all over the week. Its a fix that have been done since april 2017. This should have been released asap. Why they haven't released it yet? lol

Comment: I think they've stopped caring about the Visual Studio integration. Personally, I've moved to using Visual Studio Code for developing my Ionic application and I've been having a far better experience. JetBrains WebStorm is also decent, although not quite as good as Visual Studio Code. There are plenty of extensions in Visual Studio code to assist with Ionic, Typescript and Angular.